# Work flow field update after clone: works for SysAdmin but not for other users?

Tags: workflow, clone

What I am trying to accomplish: after an object has been cloned, via the standard Clone button, a custom field 'version number' must be incremented.

I want to accomplish this via work flow and I got this working perfectly. I created a work flow, which is triggered by the creation of an object. The work flow inspects the version number. If it is blank/null, it is updated to '1', otherwise to version number + 1. I tested it as SysAdmin and it works like a charm.

Then I tested it as a user with a non SysAdmin profile. And it doesn't work for that user. Always, the version number is filled with '1'. I don't get an error message. The profile has access to the object and the version number field.

I don't understand what is happening. The user has access to the field, or (s)he hasn't. I don't get an error message, so I guess the user has access. But why doesn't the user see the initial, cloned, value, whereas the SysAdmin does?

Edit: I split the work flow into two rules, that are functionally identical to the original single rule, but I thought, hey, let's try something else. Still the same results: working for SysAdmin, not working for non SysAdmin.

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Versie__c is an Integer field. The field updates do the obvious things.

Comment: can you test that the non admin user has permission for fie.lds and object which the workflow is referencing and updating? Also check that workflow default user is System Admin

Comment: The non admin user can see the object and field in a page layout. So I say it has read permission. And after the clone action, the field gets the value 1, while the original value of the cloned object was, e.g., 2. The field does not have an initial value in its definition. So the non admin user can update the field as well.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the WF Rule criteria and the field update formula?

Comment: Added the screenshots, some more comment. After a night's sleep, I still don't understand this.